# How do I post a flash video to a user's wall in Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to figure out how to post a flash movie to a user's wall using the Graph API in C#.

These are the args I'm passing in:

```
args["message"] = "My Message";
args["name"] = "SOME TEXT";
args["link"] = "http://www.example.com";
args["picture"] = "http://www.example.com/source.jpg";
args["source"] = "http://www.example.com/source.swf";
args["width"] = "90";
args["height"] = "90";
args["expanded_width"] = "398";
args["expanded_height"] = "224";
args["icon"] = "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/yj/r/v2OnaTyTQZE.gif";
args["caption"] = "caption";
args["description"] = "description";
dynamic result = fbApp.Api("/me/feed", args, HttpMethod.Post);
```

The result is returning a valid PostId back and everything is there with the exception of my Flash movie. The image isn't showing either.

What am I missing here? I know my syntax is off but has anyone successfully posted a Flash movie to a user's wall using the new Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you can't combine all those parameters. You can only post one of image, link, source, or message. I don't know which one takes priority though.

Comment: How would you post a source then?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't been able to get source to work, regardless of the combination of parameters I sent.